# How to add custom fields when signUpInBackground: with Parse Server?

Tags: swift, database, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

So we know `PFUser` has 3 fields: username, password and an e-mail that can be registered with it. But I would like to collect more information from my users.

How can I add other fields, like, for example, 'Age', or 'Location'?

Comment: My answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add other fields then? Like for example, 'Age', or 'Location'?

Yes, you can do that in all [Parse SDKs](http://parseplatform.org/#sdks) because Parse User is a subclass of Parse Object.

For example in the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) to add other fields like 'Age' or 'Location', you can use the following way :

```swift
let user = PFUser()
user.username = "toto"
user.password = "Secret password"
user.email = "toto@example.com"
user["Age"] = 20
user["Location"] = PFGeoPoint(latitude: 20, longitude: 20)
user.signUpInBackground()
```

I don't know exactly in which SDK you want to do that but you can adjust this example in others SDKs.
If you want another example in other language, let me know

I hope my answer was helpful